# Minimizing maximal adjacent integer sum on a circle

Tags: optimization, extremal-combinatorics

Arrange $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ on a circle. What are the arrangements that minimize the maximal sum of all adjacent $k$ integers? Some nontrivial examples of $(n,k)$ are welcome. A random algorithm that gives a probabilistic bound would be great.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Perhaps a graphic illustrating how you're arranging the integers? How are you defining "maximal sum of all adjacent $k$ integers"?

Comment: @AdrianKeister: Given a circular arrangement of those $n$ natural numbers, consider the set $K$ of $k$ adjacent natural numbers on the circle. Take the set $S$ of the sums of those elements of $k$ adjacent natural numbers on the circle. The maximum $M$ of the element of $S$ is then a function of the circular arrangement. Now find the minimal $M$ amongst all the circular arrangements. Is this clear? I can certainly write the question in the formal language. But I thought it was clearer this way. Let me know what you think of it after my explanation.

Comment: You could formulate it as a mixed integer linear optimization problem to get some examples of optimal arrangements.

Comment: @LinAlg: Good idea. I need $n^2$ binary variables with associated $2n$ inequalities to express the distinctiveness of the $n$ variables to formulate the problem in the mixed integer linear programming, don't I?

Comment: Yes. Minimizing the maximum can be phrased with purely linear constraints.

Answer (score 0):

we don't want the two largest numbers in the set: which is n and n-1 to be adjacent to each other: 
You can quickly figure out the pattern that the lower bound of the maximum adjacent sum is n+2:

[image]

The general pattern is to start with n - the greatest number - on the very top position and make sure that n-1 isn't beside n, and then if you can n-2 isn't beside either n or n-1 and n-3 isn't beside any of those and so on. I placed them exactly 2 spots away in the clockwise direction (although you could use the Counter-Clockwise convention instead).

Comment: No, it is not so simple.

Comment: @Hans Wait then what's wrong with my diagram?

Comment: Your answer is very sloppy. You do not even specify what $k$ you are using. Apparently you set $k=2$. There is no proof 2even some kind of plausibility justification.

Comment: @ Hans I have a question, if my diagram is k=2 how would k = 3 work? Would I select 2 of the numbers to the CW position and 1 on the CCW position or something else?

Comment: $k$ means the sum is over $k$ adjacent/consecutive natural numbers.

Comment: @Hans yeah but for  any odd number k wouldnt there be two ways of selecting the adjacent numbers?

Comment: What do you mean two ways? How does that matter? We are looking at the SET of all sums of $k$ adjacent natural numbers.

Comment: @Hans Just to clarify, would this diagram have k = 2 or k = 1? https://sketch.io/render/sk-6e31acc30c0a34df1aeccd57a51a507f.jpeg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79218/discussion-between-hans-and-ray-lin).